# Array inside data structure RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Is it possible to have an array inside a data structure ?

```
 D P_IacWtlDataIPWorkList...
 D                 ds                  template qualified
  * IACWTL
 D WorkKey                             like(T_IacWtl.WORKKEY)
  * use character field for sql fetch
 D WorkTitle                           like(T_IacWtl2.WRKTITLE)
 D WorkTitleNumber...
 D                                     like(T_IacWtl.WRKTITLENO)
 D TypeOfWorkTitle...
 D                                     like(T_IacWtl.WRKTITLETY)
  * IACWTT
 D TitleTypeDescription...
 d                                     like(T_IacWtt.Descr)

  *IACWCD

 D CAECode...
 d                                     like(T_IacWcd.CAECode)
 D CAECodeDescription...
 d                                     like(T_IacWcd.Descr)
  * IACWRK
 d OriginalVersionInd...
 d                                     like(T_IacWrk.WRKORGIND)
 d StatusOfWork...
 d                                     like(T_IacWrk.WRKSTS)
 d PublisherReferences...
 d                                     likeds(WorkReference) dim(11)
```

See PublisherReferences in the above DS.

Work reference DS has been defined as below:

```
 D WorkReference...
 D                 ds                  template qualified
 D Reference                     30
```

But this fails to compile in places where P_IacWtlDataIPWorkList is used.

Basically the P_IacWtlDataIPWorkList DS contains details of works and a work can have multiple publisher references. Hence, the need for an array in this case. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: "fails to compile" - with what error?  "in places where P_IacWtlDataIPWorkList is used"  show an example.

Comment: short answer, yes you can have an array in a DS.

Comment: Hi Charles, so the failure was occurring in code where an embedded sql fetch into was being done into the DS variable. And yeah, it makes sense to see it fail when a fetch is made into a DS with an array subfield. But could you please confirm if the DS declaration I showed above is indeed correct ?

Comment: The DS declaration is correct for RPG IV. The SQL precompiler has rules that are somewhat different in that not all valid RPG declarations are valid for the SQL precompiler.

Comment: @Theju112 if it wasn't valid RPG IV, you'd get a compiler error in the DS declaration.

Comment: @Theju112, if you want to check your RPG definitions in general and you're getting errors from the SQL precompiler, you can temporarily compile your source using CRTRPGMOD to see if it is complaining about any definitions. Just ignore the error messages it gives about EXEC SQL.

Comment: @Theju112, can you show the fetch you are using?